# Can't target elements that were created in a function, in another function - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my Jquery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#accordion").accordion();

  $("#addition").click(function() {

    var folders = $(".folder").length;
    var count = (1 + folders);
    var folderName = prompt("Please enter folder name");
    var addFolder = ("<div class=folder> </div>");
    var addFolderImg = '<img class=folderImg src="folder-icon.png">';
    var addFolderName = ("<h3 class=foldName>" + folderName + "</h3>");
    var addFolderMenu = ("<div class=folderMenu></div>");


    if (folders == 0) {

      $("#addition").after(addFolder);
    } else {
      $(".folder").last().after(addFolder);
    }

    $(".folder").last().append(addFolderImg);
    $(".folder").last().append(addFolderName);
    $(".folder").last().append(addFolderMenu);

    $(".folderMenu").hide();

  });


  $(".folderImg").click(function() {

    $(this).siblings(".folderMenu").toggle();

  });

});
```

For some reason the last function, where I try to toggle on the .folderMenu, only works if I move the whole action inside the first function, though not perfectly. I've had this problem while trying to target any of html elements that were created via jquery. Thank you for your time and efforts!

Comment: Since you're creating these elements dynamically, you might want to try using .on('click', function(){ vs. .click()

Comment: Didn't help in this case, but I will look in to this as this is the first time I'm encountering it. Thank you also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to run the second part within the first.  Your code will currently execute in this manner:

1. Bind a function to whenever a user clicks on the element #accordion
2. Bind a function to whenever a user clicks on an existing .folderImg element
3. User clicks on #accordion: create a new .folderImg element

The new .folderImg element will not have the binding done in step 2 automatically applied as it did not exist when you did the binding.  When you bind something, you bind it to existing elements, not future ones.

Comment: Interesting, this is something I haven't even thought about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$(".folderImg").click(function() {});` try using `$(".folderImg").on('click', function() {});`That will work for dynamically added elements.